# When to register user defaults?

Tags: swift, macos, swift3

I'm writing my first macOS app and am having trouble finding out where to register my user defaults. I need to use the value in `viewDidLoad`. On my iOS apps, I usually register it in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` but the launch sequence in macOS is different?

```
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        let dict = ["defaultPath": "/Users/mike/file.log"]
        UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: dict)
    }
}

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: NSTextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Error here since user default has not been registered
        textField.stringValue = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "defaultPath")!
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Mike, the current answer is obsolete as of Swift 3.1.  It's safe to use `init()` in those cases.  Talk to Matt about unaccepting the answer.